# How to scale by increment?

Tags: scale

I have snap turned on and it works just fine when I'm moving an object. But is there a way to have my object snap to grid increments when I am scaling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just turn on "Affect Scale" in the snapping settings.

[image]

Now just hold left `Ctrl` and your scale should snap.